# Combining NumPy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 20x100x3 [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) arrays which I want to combine into a 40 x 100 x 3 array, that is, just add more lines to the array. I am confused by which function I want: is it vstack, hstack, column_stack or maybe something else?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe it's vstack you want

```
p=array_2
q=array_2
p=numpy.vstack([p,q])
```

Comment: not sure why your answer didn't show up when I first visited the page. +1 for suggesting vstack first.

Comment: Please note that the documentation suggests to use `stack` or `concatenate` nowadays and that vstack is only supported for backwards compatibility see: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html

Answer (score 15):

One of the best ways of learning is experimenting, but I would say you want `np.vstack` although there are other ways of doing the same thing:

```
a = np.ones((20,100,3))
b = np.vstack((a,a)) 

print b.shape # (40,100,3)
```

or

```
b = np.concatenate((a,a),axis=0)
```

**EDIT**

Just as a note, on my machine for the sized arrays in the OP's question, I find that `np.concatenate` is about 2x faster than `np.vstack`

```
In [172]: a = np.random.normal(size=(20,100,3))

In [173]: c = np.random.normal(size=(20,100,3))

In [174]: %timeit b = np.concatenate((a,c),axis=0)
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.3 us per loop

In [175]: %timeit b = np.vstack((a,c))
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.1 us per loop
```

Comment: I may be, being stupid here as I've not used timeit much, but does concatenate not take 10x as many loops?

Comment: @Giltech, while timeit uses 10x more loops to benchmark `np.concatenate` (it seems to choose this automatically), the important number here is the time per loop

Comment: You should be careful about the factor of 2. Your test case is with small arrays of 6000 items and in the range of us. Simply extending the input array to (20,**10000**,3) results in **6.62 ms per loop** vs. **6.38 ms per loop**, still in favor for using concatenate directly. So for big arrays the difference shouldn't really matter.

Comment: @EnnoGröper good point. One should always perform their own benchmark/do their own profiling when the performance matters. I was just suggesting a particular method given the OP system size.

Answer (score 11):

Might be worth mentioning that

```
    np.concatenate((a1, a2, ...), axis=0)
```

is the general form and vstack and hstack are specific cases.  I find it easiest to just know which dimension I want to stack over and provide that as the argument to np.concatenate.

Answer (score 4):

I tried a little benchmark between r_ and vstack and the result is very interesting:

```
import numpy as np

NCOLS = 10
NROWS = 2
NMATRICES = 10000

def mergeR(matrices):
    result = np.zeros([0, NCOLS])

    for m in matrices:
        result = np.r_[ result, m]

def mergeVstack(matrices):
    result = np.vstack(matrices)

def main():
    matrices = tuple( np.random.random([NROWS, NCOLS]) for i in xrange(NMATRICES) )
    mergeR(matrices)
    mergeVstack(matrices)

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then I ran profiler:

```
python -m cProfile -s cumulative np_merge_benchmark.py
```

and the results:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
...
     1    0.579    0.579    4.139    4.139 np_merge_benchmark.py:21(mergeR)
...
     1    0.000    0.000    0.054    0.054 np_merge_benchmark.py:27(mergeVstack)
```

So **the vstack way is 77x faster!**

Answer (score 3):

By the way, there is also `r_`:

```
>>> from scipy import *
>>> a = rand(20,100,3)
>>> b = rand(20,100,3)
>>> a.shape
(20, 100, 3)
>>> b.shape
(20, 100, 3)
>>> r_[a,b].shape
(40, 100, 3)
>>> (r_[a,b] == vstack([a,b])).all()
True
```