# simple but weird vstack/concatenate problems (python)

Tags: python, list, numpy, concatenation

I've been reading over the documentation on numpy arrays and some of it is not making sense.
For instance,  the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740311/combining-numpy-arrays) suggest to use `np.vstack` or `np.concatenate` to combine arrays, as does many other places on the internet.
However, when I try to do this with converted `lists` to `np.arrays` is doesn't work:
"

```
>>> some_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> np.array(some_list)
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> some_Y_list = [2,1,5,6,3]
>>> np.array(some_Y_list)
array([2, 1, 5, 6, 3])
>>> dydx = np.diff(some_Y_list)/np.diff(some_list)
>>> np.vstack([dydx, dydx[-1]])"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    np.vstack([dydx, dydx[-1]])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 226, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate(map(atleast_2d,tup),0)
ValueError: array dimensions must agree except for d_0
```

Any way that I can do this?

All I am needing this for in this instance is just to make the derivatives of any order the same shape as my X array given by the user so I can do processing.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following won't work except in some very limited circumstances:

```
np.vstack([dydx, dydx[-1]])
```

Here, `dydx` is an array and `dydx[-1]` is a scalar.

It's unclear what you're trying to achieve, but did you perhaps mean to stack them horizontally:

```
np.hstack([dydx, dydx[-1]])
```

?

```
In [38]: np.hstack([dydx, dydx[-1]])
Out[38]: array([-1,  4,  1, -3, -3])
```

Comment: I thought of that, but `[dydx[-1],]` or ` [dydx[-1]]` in place of `dydx[-1]` didn't help either.

Comment: @chase: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Aha `np.hstack()` works!  It really was that simple, thank you much!

Comment: I was just trying to get the derivatives of my function to be the same length or shape as the original function.  The `np.diff()` function will shave off a number each time, so I just made the assumption that the last numb is not too important and can be whatever the second to last number was for the derivatives.