# How to concat many numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to concatenate many numpy arrays, I put each array in one file, In fact the problem that I have a lot of files, Memory can't support to create a big array `Data_Array = np.zeros((1000000,7000))`, where I will put all my files.    So, I found in this question [Combining NumPy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740311/combining-numpy-arrays/6767394#6767394) that I can use `np.concatenate`:

```
file1= np.load('file1_Path.npy')
file2= np.load('file2_Path.npy')
file3= np.load('file3_Path.npy')
file4= np.load('file4_Path.npy')
dataArray=np.concatenate((file1, file2, file3, file4), axis=0)
test= dataArray.shape
print(test)
print (dataArray)
print (dataArray.shape)
plt.plot(dataArray.T)
plt.show()
```

This way gives me a very good result, but now, I need to replace `file1, file2, file3, file4` by the path to the folder of my files:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import glob
import os, sys
fpath ="Path_To_Big_File"
npyfilespath =r'Path_To_Many_Numpy_Files'  
os.chdir(npyfilespath)
npfiles= glob.glob("*.npy")
npfiles.sort()
for i,npfile in enumerate(npfiles):
    dataArray=np.concatenate(npfile, axis=0)
np.save(fpath, all_arrays)
```

It gives me this error:

```
np.concatenate(npfile, axis=0)

ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

Could you please help me to make this method `np.concatenate` works?

Comment: Have you tried saving and reading the data in an HDF5 file? It supports streaming the data in pieces

Comment: @NilsWerne, Thank you very much for your answer, but I don't try HDF5 file, because my goal is to have a big numpy file which containd all my files, this file will help me to make may analysis.

Comment: What about if you added some sort of "truthy-test," e.g. `if npfile: np.concatenate(npfile, axis=0)`... That is, `if npfile is not None`... You could also use a try-except block to just pass over `ValueError`s.

Comment: Wait a minute... You're trying to concatenate `i`, the *index* of the `npfiles` list; not the actual file itself.

Comment: @not_a_robot sorry , It was a mistake, I correct it

Comment: In the 1st case you load files and concatenate a list of the resulting arrays.  In the second `npfiles` is a list of file names.  So `npfile` is just a string.  What's the point of putting that in concatenate?  You haven't even done a np.load on it.

Comment: If an array is too big to load into memory it is too big to plot

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use large arrays, just use np.memmap instead of loading the data into memory. The advantage of memmap is that data is always saved to disk when necessary. For example, you can create a memory mapped array in the following way:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.memmap('myFile',dtype=np.int,mode='w+',shape=(1000000,8000))
```

You can then use 'a' as a normal numpy array.
The limit is then your hard disk ! This creates a file on your hard disk that you can read later. You just change mode to 'r' and read data from the array.
More info about memmap here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html

In order to fill that array from npy files of shape (1,8000), just write:

```
for i,npFile in enumerate(npfFiles):
  a[i,:]=np.load(npFile)
a.flush()
```

The flush method insures everything has been written on disk

Comment: By using this method I created an array with shape (1000000,8000) but how to put my numpy files saved in my folder in that file?

Comment: Do they have the same shapes and types?

Comment: In fact the shape of each  file is (1,8000), they are a numpy files, I want to put them all in the same file, so in order to have a correct work, the resulted file must have as shape (1000000,8000) , I have million numpy file in input.