# Convert two numpy array to dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to convert two numpy array to one `DataFrame` containing two columns.
The first numpy array 'images' is of shape `102, 1024`.
The second numpy array 'label' is of shape `(1020, )`

My core code is:

```
images=np.array(images)
label=np.array(label)
l=np.array([images,label])
dataset=pd.DataFrame(l)
```

But it turns out to be an error saying that:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1020,1024) into shape (1020)
```

What should I do to convert these two numpy array into two columns in one dataframe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining NumPy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740311/combining-numpy-arrays)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can't stack them easily, especially if you want them as different columns, because you can't insert a 2D array in one column of a DataFrame, so you need to convert it to something else, for example a `list`.

So something like this would work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
images = np.array(images)
label = np.array(label)
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'label': label, 'images': list(images)}, columns=['label', 'images'])
```

This will create a `DataFrame` with 1020 rows and 2 columns, where each item in the second column contains 1D arrays of length 1024.

Answer (score 2):

Coming from engineering, I like the visual side of creating matrices.

```
matrix_aux = np.vstack([label,images])
matrix     = np.transpose(matrix_aux)
df_lab_img = pd.DataFrame(matrix)
```

Takes a little bit more of code but leaves you with the Numpy array too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use hstack

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataset = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((images, label.reshape(-1, 1))))
```